# Instantiate template using dynamic bool variable

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I want to return a type from function depending on a boolean flag. The idea was to create instances of a Test class later in the program operating with this traits structure that would hold the actual type. However, now I don't know what the return type of a traits function would be.

```
class Test {
public:
    template <typename T>
    class Traits {
    public:
        typedef T type;
    };
    ...
};

??? Test::Options::traits(){
    if(timer){
        return Test::Traits<Timeable<Test>>();
    } else {
        return Test::Traits<Test>();
    }
}
```

Comment: C++, unfortunately, does not work this way. There's good news, though. C++17 has a `std::variant` type that can be used to effectively do this. But whoever calls it will just have to do a little bit extra work to figure out which type was returned. Alternatively, if `timer` is effectively `constexpr`, this can be done with specialization.

Answer (score 2):

A function can only return *one specific* type.

There is no way in C++ to overload on return type.

You *cannot* dynamically change the return type of a function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is runtime polymorphism, while C++ templates are compile-time polymorphism.

How are you going to use the return value? something like `if (its type is something) ... else ... ?` In this case you can use `std::variant` (C++17).

Or are you going to just call its methods that will be present in all variants? In this case you can use good old inheritance. Extract a common interface to a pure abstract class (often called "interface" anyway), derive from it all types you'd like to return. Ah, and don't return it by value. You can return e.g. `std::unique_ptr<YourInterfaceType>` (fits your example though involves dynamic memory allocation), or any other kind of reference